# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError for external library

Tags: java, maven

I have a simple program that parse csv file into json objects. 
I added json.simple-1.1 into my maven. The content of my maven is like this:

```
    <groupId>IoT</groupId>
    <artifactId>ETL2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>



    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>ETL2</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I try to execute the jar artifact in the terminal. 
I get these errors.

> Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and
>   try again **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/json/simple/parser/ParseException     at**
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)    at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)    at
>   java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)   at
>   java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)    at
>   sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
>     at
>   sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
>   **> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.json.simple.parser.ParseException     at**
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     ... 7 more

I read in here that

> This is caused when there is a class file that your code depends on
>   and it is present at compile time but not found at runtime. Look for
>   differences in your build time and runtime classpaths.

That's why I suspect that my maven configuration might not be correct.

Comment: I have checked the artifact and and confirm, class is available in the package. checked at [maven jar lib](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple/1.1)], maybe try to do standard `maven clean, maven install, maven compile` if helps. Or you can try to link lib manually as external lib dependecy through IDE, to test if that will works.. Except this don´t have more idea. But maybe that helps :) ( `-X` should work for debug info)

Answer (score 2):

Change your plugin to the below snippet and it is highly recommended you read [How to build an executable jar with dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven)

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>ETL2</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                  <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: I tried your snippet. The descriptorRef rag is shown in red. It is now allowed to use it in here.

Comment: @FarhoodHosseinpour i don't know what you're using or why it's in red. but it's perfect in my version of eclipse. in both version 3.0.2 and also 3.6 which my spring boot uses.